# How to properly set a datatable to an gridview in code with an ObjectDataSource?

Tags: data-binding, datatable, objectdatasource

I have an ObjectDataSource with an ID of ObjectDataSource1 on a webpage.  I also have a gridview in which I am binding the ObjectDataSource.ID to the GridView.DataSourceID.  The problem I get is when text is changed in a textbox, the code calls BrokerageTransactions.GetAllWithDt which returns a DataTable.  I want to set this datatable as the DataSource for the GridView, but it is telling me that I can't set the DataSouce and DataSourceId together.  How can I fix this?  Code is below.  Also. Why can't you set a DataSourceID and a DataSource when using an ObjectDataSource?

Thanks,
X

```
protected void BrokerageChange(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BrokerageTransactions brokerageaccountdetails = 
                          new BrokerageTransactions();

    DataSet ds = BrokerageAccount.GetBrkID2(new 
                 Guid(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()), 
                 ddlBrokerageDetails.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        brokerageaccountdetails.BrokerageId = 
                                new Guid(dr["BrkrgId"].ToString());
    }

    ddlBrokerageDetails.SelectedItem.Value = 
                        brokerageaccountdetails.BrokerageId.ToString();

    if (txtTransactionsTo.Text != "" 
        && txtTransactionsFrom.Text != "")
        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = 
        "convert(CreateDt,System.DateTime)>Convert('" + 
         Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsFrom.Text) + "',System.DateTime) 
         and Convert(CreateDt,System.DateTime)<convert('"
         + Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsTo.Text.ToString()) + 
         "',System.DateTime)";
    else if (txtTransactionsFrom.Text != "")
            ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression =
            "convert(CreateDt,System.DateTime)>convert('" +
             Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsFrom.Text) + 
            "',System.DateTime)";
    else if (txtTransactionsTo.Text != "")
            ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = 
            "convert(CreateDt,System.DateTime)
            <convert('" 
            + Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsTo.Text.ToString()) +  
            "',System.DateTime)";
    else
        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = " ";

    grvBrokerage.DataSourceID = ObjectDataSource1.ID;
    grvBrokerage.DataBind();

    DateTime dtTransFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1900");
    DateTime dtTransTo = System.DateTime.Today;

    //TransactionsTo Box is Empty
    if ((txtTransactionsFrom.Text.Length > 2) 
    && (txtTransactionsTo.Text.Length < 2)) 
    {
        dtTransFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsFrom.Text);
        dtTransTo = System.DateTime.Today;
    }

    //TransactionsFrom Box is Empty
    if ((txtTransactionsFrom.Text.Length < 2) 
    && (txtTransactionsTo.Text.Length > 2))
    {
       dtTransFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1900");
       dtTransTo = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsTo.Text);
    }

    //TransactionsFrom Box and TransactionsTo Box is Not Empty
    if ((txtTransactionsFrom.Text.Length > 2) 
    && (txtTransactionsTo.Text.Length > 2))
    {
        dtTransFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsFrom.Text);
        dtTransTo = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTransactionsTo.Text);
    }
    // Fails Here
    grvBrokerage.DataSource = 
    BrokerageTransactions.GetAllWithDt(brokerageaccountdetails.BrokerageId, 
                                       dtTransFrom, 
                                       dtTransTo);
    grvBrokerage.DataBind();  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got 2 options:

- Do not use the ObjectDataSource at
  all. You just use the DataSource
  property and Set It grammatically
  every time.
- You use the DataSourceID property of the GridView and Add 2 plain asp:Parameters with default value set. On the ObjectDataSource_Selecting Event you set these parameters through e.InputParameters[]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What would these two parameters be?

Thanks

Comment: Those parameters for you would be the From and To dates for the BrokerageTransactions In your example code this would be dtTransFrom and dtTransTo.